# How to open a popup window from a webpage on iphone

Tags: iphone, popup, window, new-operator

I'm trying to open a popup window (to display another webpage) from my webpage, when an hyperlink is clicked. I'm not able to achieve this on iPhone. I was wondering if there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari and `UIWebView` do not support pop up windows.

Mobile Safar is capable of opening a new tab (or page), but not using the conventional methods of opening popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://anotherwebsite.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

that will open another safari window in the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to force opening a mobile version of your website in the iPhone. On that page you can put a direct "click here" link to your popup page.

Comment: If you provide such suggestion, it's always good to post a code example with it. By doing this, your answer will be way more valuable. :)